# pH sensor box - ADS1115

Tags: esp8266, bnc, ph

I made a pH sensor box to monitoring my hydroponic culture.

I built a PH sensor box (see Frtitzing) to use for my hydroponics system with:
- Esp8266
- ADS1115
- BNC + pH probe (2X)

Unfortunately the pH measurement is very unstable (see grafana graph.)

When I shake the box a little, the measurement varies. I also have a sinusoidal signal with both probes.

What is wrong in the wiring?

[image])
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Fritzing can produce schematic diagrams as well as wiring diagrams.  Schematics are of more use when discussing the function of circuits than wiring diagrams.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3):

Breadboards are notorious for loose, wobbly connections.

They are also known for having high resistance contacts and stray capacitance between connections.

It probably doesn't help much to have long wires connected your breadboards, with the wires run up around that Node MCU module with its wifi or bluetooth antenna.

Pretty much all of your wiring (breadboards and terminal blocks and long wires near a transmitter) says "make a mess of my signals, please."

Another thing is that typical 5V USB powersupplies a generally very noisy.  Depending on whether or not your ADC and pH board have their own regulators/filters, you may be getting a lot of noise that way.

Comment: thank for your advice. it's just a prototype. but I will try to make a cleaner circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You may have common ground noise due to the fact that you share the same ground wiring for the supply and for the measurement voltage from the pF sensors to the ADC board. If the voltage level coming out of the pH sensor is really low, this can represent a serious problem.

Here’s something you can try:

Instead of using the ADC in single-ended mode, use it in differential mode. Move the output of the second pH sensor to the ADC’s A2 input; solder a separate ground wire connecting the ground of the first pH sensor to the ADC’s A1 input (if you twist it with the existing yellow wire connecting to A0, it will be even better); do the same thing for the second pH sensor connecting it to the ADC’s A3 input. Then change your code to make sure the ADC is programmed to operate in differential mode where A0-A1 measures the pH from the first sensor and A2-A3 measures the pH from the second sensor.

Let me know whether or not this makes any difference.

Comment: thank you. I will try this and I will come back to you!

Comment: I just changed the wiring. I also passed ADS1115 in differential (A0-A3 and A1-A3) mode rather single end. I get much better results with less noise. On node red I use the smooth function (10 values) to smooth the curve. How to get the mean of the sinusoid?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qleAK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmokf.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP1MU.png

Comment: @Laurent - I noticed you connect the 3V3 supply to A3 in your diagram. This way, you're going to couple all the logic noise from 3V3 to your measurement. I recommend you connect A3 to ground instead. The ground wire should not go to anywhere else except to A3 and to GND connection(s) on the sensor board(s). My original suggestion to connect separate GND wires to A1 and A3 should give you the best results. Regarding the low frequency sine wave you are getting, it can be the result of aliasing of the AC power frequency. What is your sampling rate? You may have to add filters before the ADC.